# How to create dynamic tags in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have the following locals file with names of resource groups and maps of tags per environment

```
    locals{
           identity-rgs = ["prod-dc", "prod-okta", "dev-dc", "dev-okta"]

           prod_okta_tags = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Prod"
                  "Product" = "Okta"
                            }
          dev_okta_tags = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Dev"
                  "Product" = "Okta"
                            }
           dev_dc_tags = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Dev"
                  "Product" = "DC"
                            }
              prod_dc_tags = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Dev"
                  "Product" = "DC"
                            }
```

Main.tf - creates a  Azure resource group from my locals files

```
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "identity-rgs" {
      count    = length(local.ind-identity-rgs)
      name     = local.ind-identity-rgs[count.index]
      location = ....
      tags =
```

How do I assign tags for each resource group dynamically as I iterate through the list?

such as identity-rgs[0] should have the prod_dc_tags and identity-rgs[2] should have the dev_dc tags?

I'm trying a if else conditon but can't get it to work

```
tags = "${local.identity-rgs == "prod-dc" ? local.prod_dc_tags:0}"
```

> Inconsistent conditional result types
> │
> │   on create-resource-groups.tf line 297, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "identity-rgs":
> │  297: tags = "${local.identity-rgs == "prod-dc" ? local.prod_dc_tags:0}"
> │     ├────────────────
> │     │ localidentity-rgs is tuple with 4 elements
> │     │ local.prod_dc_tags is object with 10 attributes
> │
> │ The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are object and number, respectively.

Can this be done via a dynamic block as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that the way you are trying. The easiest way is to re-define your locals:

```
    locals{
      identity-rgs = ["prod-dc", "prod-okta", "dev-dc", "dev-okta"]

     tags = { 
          prod_okta = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Prod"
                  "Product" = "Okta"
                            },
          dev_okta_tags = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Dev"
                  "Product" = "Okta"
                            },
           dev_dc_tags = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Dev"
                  "Product" = "DC"
                            },
              prod_dc_tags = {
                  "Key1" = "Value1" 
                  "Key2" = "Value2" 
                  "Environment" = "Dev"
                  "Product" = "DC"
                            }
          }
```

Then, with `for_each` (its better then `count` as it does not depend on order of items):

```
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "identity-rgs" {
      for_each = toset(local.ind-identity-rgs)

      tags = local.tags[each.key]
   }
```